# Export mykeystore.pfx to X.509 Certificate using openssl

Tags: pkcs#12

I have generated mykeystore.pfx using command line keytool. Can anyone tell me how to generate   X.509 certificate (PEM) using openssl please?

Answer (score 3):

I found this as one way to generate the same:

**openssl pkcs12 -in mykeystore.pfx -out mykeystore.pem -nodes**